# Calling Bash script from PHP not outputting correct values

Tags: php, bash

I am attempting to call a bash script from PHP. When I run this bash script on my text file from the command line, I get the desired output. However, through PHP, it simply outputs nothing.
The following is my PHP code.

```
$output = shell_exec("path/to/script.sh tmp/file.txt");
echo $output;
```

Where path/to/script is, as it sounds, the path to the bash script, and tmp/file.txt is the argument for the script. The output of this is blank, yet when I run the bash script with the same input in the command line, it executes properly. Why is this?

Comment: can you show us exactly what is your PHP script and what you type in the command line?

Comment: is `tmp/file.txt` a relative path, sometimes you can have issues with what the working directory is when calling scripts from other locations.  I see this a lot more on windows.  So it may be that it is failing silently too.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without seeing script.sh however I can see that shell_exec outputs null when it fails.

You could try using the `exec()` function to review the exit code of the script.
[php manual exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

so the code would be:

```
exec("path/to/script.sh tmp/file.txt", $output);
echo $output;
```

You might find that it's a permission issue stopping the process from making changes to it.

try changing the file permissions with `chmod 777 tmp/file.txt`